# semantically similar word for natural language processing in German

Tags: python, nlp, semantics, similarity

I am working on natural language programming in the German Language in which I need to categorize words according to the meaning of the words. E.g 'Communication', 'Social skills', 'Interpersonal Skills' belongs to 'Communication skills' and so forth.

Basically, the words need to sort based on the similarity of the meaning it has with given set of standard words. 
I have tried `Levenstein-distance`, `edit-distance` and open-source `fuzzy` string matching technique but the result are not satisfying.

Best results come from using `Longest-common Subsequence` the list of words but I want to match the words based on the underlying meaning of the words.

Comment: Please don't use SO as a [Google service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordNet#Other_languages) for [off topic questions, see #4](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is "semantic similarity". One possible option is to use Spacy or another NLP framework. You would want to explore word 2 vector algorithms to help with you task.

[Semantic Similarity with Spacy](https://spacy.io/usage/vectors-similarity)